# SublimeLinter-contrib-remark-lint

Tags: sublimetext, sublimelinter

I am trying to get remark-lint working in Sublime Text using [SublimeLinter-contrib-remark-lint](https://github.com/j616/SublimeLinter-contrib-remark-lint).

From Sublime Text console I keep getting `WARNING: remarklint cannot locate 'remark'`.

How could I go about this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Dont link to some document. Rather give enough information here so we understand which steps you actually took ...